# Lightbox from inline images in hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, colorbox

I have a hidden div with some inline images:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="dispay:none;">
   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." />
      ...
   <img .../>
</div>
```

Now, I wan't to have a lightbox, which will dispay those images. The problem is most lightbox implementations accept anchors pointing to image files as an input.

Colobox, can take inline html but it can't take multiple html fragments to render gallery like (with prev and next buttons) experience. Do you have any ideas:

1. if colorbox can be configured to diplay this sort of data?
2. Is there alternative jQuery plugin which doeas that?
3. How to quickly implement this, if there is no working solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Colobox, can take inline html but it can't take multiple html fragments to render gallery

Sure it can.  Something like this should work, but there are other alternatives as well:

```
$('#mydiv img').colorbox({
    rel:'my-group', 
    inline: true,
    open: true,
    href: function(){ return this; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are bound to be a few lightboxes that work on the basis of hidden content being revealed (if it's important to keep your markup the way it is). [Bootstrap Lightbox](http://jbutz.github.com/bootstrap-lightbox/) is one of them.

But if you already have a preference for Colorbox, I'm sure it could do the task: [this demo](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/) showcases examples where multiple images are invoked. If it's a problem with the data-URI, you can use that as the link — if it's a problem with the necessity of having separate links for the other images in the group, you can hide those with `display:none` (the same as you're currently doing with your `img`).

Comment: No i don't have preference for colorbox ;)

Comment: OK. So what are you looking for exactly? What's wrong with Bootstrap Lightbox (answer to point 2) and Colorbox (answer to point 1)?